# How to make a horizontal scrolling menu in Unity 3d 4.5

Tags: unity, gui, ui-design, menu

I want to make a horizontal scrolling menu that will hold the levels of a game but I have a little idea about how to make it so it would be very great if anyone help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [NGUI](http://www.tasharen.com/?page_id=140). It's the best for UI before 4.6 (I havn't tried 4.6 UI yet so, I cannot tell which one is better). If you have some budget, I recommend buy NGUI 3.7.x version. It's a lot lot more convenient than 2.7 version and less buggy. If you do not have a budget, you can use 2.7 version. After that, use Scroll View in NGUI to build the scrolling menu. More info on [this youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UK3aMHRfgcw&feature=youtu.be).

Comment: NGUI is definitely better that the new UI, but the native UI is *really good* and, well, free.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are new to Unity and know a bit now about the usual functions it shouldn't be difficult for you.

You could simply make a bunch of UI buttons, that each one of them will have the sprite as a picture of the level you want to load. Only one will be inside the canvas, while the others can be fully out of it, or barely showing up. On a left/right button press, you could translate all the buttons right/left suiting your needs.

You know you should just start working on it instead of thinking about it.

Answer (score -1):

I used [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lUun2xW6FJ4) to create an GUI with a scrollable panel (vertical in my case but is trivial to change alignment).
Using unity 4.6 start using canvas, add panel and play with its components. Everything is well explained in the tutorial.

Comment: This seems like a link answer